# As an intern, how to ask for a permanent job?

Tags: internship, careers, employment

I've been interning at an almost medium size company for a year (full time in the Summer months and part-time during school). I've been moved around from training, to sales operations due to some organizational changes but I've found a mentor in my newest supervisor and I feel that sales operations is a field I'd like to pursue. I would like to work here full time after college is finished in 10 months, but there are some issues:

- Their hiring process is a mystery to me and my supervisor (Only been here since December)
- The company hasn't been doing all that well
- Our president blames all our problems on sales (the position I want is in sales).
- My degree isn't sales related, its Management Information Systems

However, I'm pretty well liked within the departments I've worked for. I've worked closely with members of the leadership team, and they like me.  I'm usually requested to do work for other departments and I am always open to those requests and attempt to help solve those problems.

Is there a specific way I can leverage my the skills I've honed at the company and my internal workplace connections to find myself a permanent position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just e-mail your direct supervisor that you've really enjoyed your internship, and that you'd appreciate help applying for a full-time position.

Nice and simple. It's premature to worry about how the company's doing, and the problem being Sales means they want good people there. Feel free to consider how much you want the job once you have an offer in hand.

Answer (score -3):

First off, why would you want to work for a company that is not doing so well, permanently ? Do you have the grand illusion of reverting back the slide of the company into non-existence, single-handedly ?

In an unlikely event you have such an idea, and you know for a fact that, president is blaming the sales team for the failure of the company, why not reach out to the head of sales and make your intentions known, with supporting evidence of how you are planning to succeed in this position, while (1) your current position is not sales related; (2) you are just an intern with no real life job experience ?

If you can make a case for these, may be they want to hire you. But I wouldn't go to the sales manager/director, saying things like "president thinks, your team is the cause for the failure of this company" or anything implying something like that. Just bring out the positive and how your contribution is going to make life better for the sales team.

Basically, SELL YOURSELF !!

Comment: We are in the oil & gas field. So I'd argue most oil & gas companies really aren't doing all that well currently. I'd like to work for the company because cost of living in this area and just because a company is not doing well doesn't mean it isn't working towards a better direction. The current head of sales is my supervisor, and our president regularly preaches that everything is sales fault.